# IE8 append only running once

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, append

I have a script which grabs some JSON via AJAX and inserts it into two columns using a  function to insert the data into a simple HTML template:

```
function projectTemplate(obj) {
    var template = '<div class="result '+searchResults+'"><a href="'+obj.url+'"><span class="title">'+obj.title+'</span><span class="desc">'+obj.desc+'</span></a><span class="topics">'+obj.topics+'</span>';
    if (obj.status != '') {
        template += ' | <span class="status">'+obj.status+'</span></div>';
    }
    template += '</div>';
    return template;
}

function processResults(data) {
    ajaxData = $.parseJSON(data);
    [...]
    if (typeof ajaxData.pages !== 'undefined') {
        var resultCount = 0, displayCount = 0;
        for (var key in ajaxData.pages) {
            resultCount++;
        }
        for (var key in ajaxData.pages) {
            var obj = ajaxData.pages[key];
            if (searchResults) {
                $('.col-left').append(projectTemplate(obj));
            } else {
                if (displayCount < (resultCount/2)) {
                    $('.col-left').append( projectTemplate(obj) );
                } else {
                    $('.col-right').append( projectTemplate(obj) );
                }
                displayCount++;
            }
            //console.log(key);
        }
    } else {
        $('.results h2 span').text('');
        var pageType = (searchResults) ? 'pages' : 'projects';
        $('#ajax-article-list .col-left').html('<strong class="no">No ' + pageType + ' found.</strong>');
    }
}
```

The trouble is that IE8 loops through each element in `ajaxData.pages` but it appears to append the results on top of one another, so I end up with only one (even when I know there are many more). Firebug Lite shows just one entry. The page in question is here http://www.climatexchange.org.uk/adapting-to-climate-change/, although it happens all over the site.

Any ideas? It doesn't seem to be a CSS problem because the nodes aren't physically being added to the DOM, so I think it must be an issue with `append()`, but I can't see anything invalid with the code that's being generated by the template (which seems to be one scenario in which IE8 trips over `append()`.

**EDIT:** the problem is with the templating function, not `append()`. If I remove the test

```
    if (obj.status != '') {
        template += ' | <span class="status">'+obj.status+'</span></div>';
    }
```

it works fine in IE8. I'm now having some difficulty finding a test which works in IE8 (all other browsers seem fine with testing for an empty string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `</div>` in the test as well as one outside it, so the template's generated markup was invalid. IE8 trips up on invalid markup whereas better browsers are more forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the `obj` always has a property `status`. Can you check like:

```
if ( ( obj.status != "undefined" ) && ( obj.status != '' ) ) {
    template += ' | <span class="status">'+obj.status+'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this by testing `if (obj.status && obj.status.length)` but the problem was my template's invalid markup :)